# Does a static_cast to the same (primitive) type produce any code?

Tags: c++, casting

I guess it's all said in the title...

But here's an example. Given

```
void functionThatTakesAFloat(float par);
float f = 3.5f;
```

does

```
functionThatTakesAFloat(static_cast<float>(f));
```

produce any additionial code compared to

```
functionThatTakesAFloat(f);
```

or is this `static_cast` completely eliminated by the compiler?

Edit:
I'm using VC++ (2010)

Comment: Wow, someone wants to close this as “too localized”. Not sure I'd agree. This is actually a pretty interesting question, although it would benefit from the OP specifying the compiler he's wondering about.

Comment: @JonathanSterling: I think it is too localized as it depends on compiler options, compiler and possible platform. None given in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer here is that by definition a cast from `float` to `float` is a no-op.  There is no conceivable code that could worth emitting for this cast.  It may be true that some compiler in this universe emits unquestionably redundant code in this case, but it is safe to assume that you will never encounter such a compiler.

Answer (score 11):

5.2.9 /

```
-2- An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T
    using a static_cast of the form static_cast<T>(e) if the
    declaration ``"T t(e);"'' is well-formed, for some invented
    temporary variable t (dcl.init). The effect of such an explicit
    conversion is the same as performing the declaration and
    initialization and then using the temporary variable as the
    result of the conversion. <cont...>
```

So given:

```
float my_float = ...;
```

...this...

```
f(static_cast<float>(my_float));
```

...must be equivalent to...

```
float temp = my_float;
f(temp);
```

Whether it's actually followed that literally, and generates a temp in non-optimised builds, would be up to the compiler.  If you don't trust your optimiser to remove this (if it was ever inserted), then you should try another compiler... ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally compiler should never produce extra code for any casting operation (except `dynamic_cast<>`) especially for such primitive types.

Comment: But what about a static_cast from float to int, for example? I guess there is some assembler instruction needed to do the job. reinterpret_cast is the only type of cast where I can't see the need to produce additional code, ever.

Comment: @Robert Hegner: A `reinterpret_cast` between two different types has an unspecified behavior (aka. it depends on the compiler/implementation) It may change the pointer address so even there, I would be careful.

Comment: @ereOn: That's interesting! Under what circumstances would reinterpret_cast change the pointer address?

Comment: @Robert Hegner: Well, I never observed it but the standard says it can happen. The only guarantee you have with `reinterpret_cast` is that if you cast a variable of type `A` to a `B` then to a `A` again, you get the original pointer. Nothing more.